# How to run JavaScript code when a form is being reset?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events

I know we can attach a handler to the form `onsubmit`... But how can we add a handler to the form reset event? (usually when clicking on `<input type="reset">`)

Or... Maybe there is no such event... So the question becomes on how to work-around that?

(right now, I want to run a handler *after* the reset event; but someday I might need to run *before* the reset event)

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27949904/2835520)

Comment: @MansApps: That would break the reset button if JavaScript is off. (Arguably, very few people use reset button, and very few have JavaScript off.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_Event_Reference/reset), the `<form>` tag supports an `onreset` event.

`Onreset` fires before the actual resetting of the form; there doesn't appear to be any event for after resetting.  I tested to see if the reset would fire an `onchange` event for the inputs whose values are reset, but it does not appear to.

A workaround for doing something after resetting might be to set a flag on reset, and then use the `onblur` event of the reset button (so after you reset, it would run the next time you click on something else).  An alternate workaround, of course, is to trigger a setTimeout so that your script would run a short time after the reset.  Either one is a bit of a hack, I'm afraid.

Comment: Accepting your answer because you cited a good reference. (even though I was kinda expecting a W3C or Mozilla Developer Center link)

Comment: Huh... I should have tested before... Using `onreset` will run the script BEFORE resetting, and not after.

Comment: Instead of registering a `blur` event handler, in your `reset` event handler, you can call `setTimeout` with a timeout value of `0` which has the effect of scheduling the function (the one you specify as the first argument to `setTimeout`) to run after current script "frame" processes. All your form controls will have been reset by then, which is why you'd want to have your code run then.

Answer (score 4):

found an answer to this that worked for me so I thought I'd post it for anyone else who came across this.

Instead of `<input type='reset'>`, you can use a `<button>` element with a click handler that first calls the `form.reset()` method, then you can add whatever scripting you need to happen after the reset action.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "reset" event of the "form" element

```
<form action="form_action.php" onreset="return confirm('Do you really want to reset the form?');">

....

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
<form onreset="action()">
```

Seems to work for me for running the script before resetting the form. As for after ... I don't think it's supported, possibly a setTimeout would do the trick.