# jQuery can't clear specific input with .val('')

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I've been looking and looking for an error here as I can't clear the input #keywordsearch when clicking on the reset button in my HTML. However, I can't find anything - can you see an issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/eKWyY/

Here's my JS:

```
$('#dirreset').click(function() {
            $('#fatform option').each(function(index) {
                $(this).removeAttr("selected");
            });
            $('#keywordsearch').val('');
        });
```

Thanks for any help, it's driving me a bit mad!

Osu

Comment: Your code works... You have a initial value of "asf" which will never be cleared however if thats what you're thinking of. If you remove your value from the input `value="asf"`you will have a completly empty input. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clicking Reset button, the entries are reset to the default values. And `asf` is your default value, so it wont clear, So change

```
<input type="reset" name="osu_directory_search_reset" value="Reset" id="dirreset">
```

to

```
<input type="button" name="osu_directory_search_reset" value="Reset" id="dirreset">
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKWyY/9/)

Answer (score 4):

The default JavaScript *reset* is being called after your `.click()` function, which resets the input back to the default value of `asf`.

If you want to avoid executing the default reset functionality use jQuery's [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or more simply add a `return false;` to the end of your function. For example

```
$('#dirreset').click(function() {
    $('#keywordsearch').val('');
    return false;
});
```

Alternatively change the type of the `<input>` to `"button"` which will not have the default *reset* functionality executed after your function. However, you may need to do some extra work if you are wanting to mimic the *reset*.

Comment: Thanks @andyb (and everyone for the answers), the first option clears everything which is useful to know. Changing input to button works in this case

Answer (score 4):

After click on "reset" button your click event executes but after that it reset's the form. That time "asf" will come back to the input field since it is initial value.

Try to look into following.

[How to execute code after html form reset with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319289/how-to-execute-code-after-html-form-reset-with-jquery)

Comment: +1 the question linked in your answer has a really good example of how to customise the reset

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the default value  "asf" you have to change the input type `reset`to `button`

Answer (score 0):

As you have specified the value as `asf` on clearing the value attribute you will get the default value only.

One suggestion you can use the placeholder attribute of input type if you want to show a little hint to the user about the input.

Example
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder

Answer (score 0):

try below code its works.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eKWyY/11/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#dirreset').click(function()
    {
        $('#fatform option').each(function(index)
        {
             $(this).removeAttr("selected");
        });
        $('#keywordsearch').attr('value','');
    });
});
```

Use `attr`.