# Which browsers does the form 'reset' event not bubble?

Tags: javascript, html

According to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset_event), the reset event isn't specified as an event that bubbles. Which browsers does 'reset' not bubble?

Comment: If I recall correctly, you can't have nested `<form>` in HTML. So, as `reset` event is for `<form>` only,  bubbling doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: The use case (and please let me know if there's an easier way) is that 'reset' doesn't trigger 'input' events for input elements, which means that if an input element needs to know when its value has changed, it also needs to listen to form reset.  These elements are added via code, so my options are either listening to the bubbling reset on document, or use a mutation observer and find the parent form when the element is connected (added to dom).

Comment: @Pac0 You can have multiple forms on a page, and might want it to bubble out to a container.

Comment: Ok, I get the usecase. This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319289/how-to-execute-code-after-html-form-reset-with-jquery ?